# Dynamic Choice of Colors

Tags: javascript, colors, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map and I want to assign colors to each "feature." The number of features can be different depending on changing geojson data. I am guessing there is some algorithm to do this.

Here is the code: (on each feature I would like to set the color to be different not the given color, because the data doesn't have a color)

```
var geomap = L.geoJson(geojson, {
            //TODO: change the colors to be randomly separated and updated based on the # of features
            //TODO: Should change the feature properties to be the population and zone number -- show this in the pop-up instead of the "description"
            style: function (feature) {
                return {color: feature.properties.color};
            },
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.zone);
            }
        });
```

So if I have 5 or 100 features I want to have different colors for each. Any hints or algorithms? This is in JavaScript obviously.

Comment: If you know the number of features, you can use this: http://blog.adamcole.ca/2011/11/simple-javascript-rainbow-color.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple tool for generator large amounts of random colors is https://github.com/davidmerfield/randomColor. 
You can use it like

```
randomColor({
   count: 10,
   hue: 'green'
});
```

If you want more control over the color generation, [Chroma.js](https://github.com/gka/chroma.js) might be a better choice for you. I recommend using some of the [Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) categorical scales for the use case you describe.